# SED command: How -i and -e work

Tags: unix, sed, sh

I'm using the sed command for the first time to try and replace one file with another file in a txt/fsf file. Can somebody help me understand how -i and -e work here?

With my code, I am iterating through various folders and copying and exsisting file to each folder and renaming the title. 
It seems that when I omit the -e, then I get errors at the sed command doesn't work. However, with this current code, the cp command is working just fine until I added the sed line. Now the cp command is outputting two files per folder ${i}_design.fsf and ${i}_design.fsf-e

I am not sure what the -e file is. The file seems to be identical to the original design.fsf file.  Is this related to the sed command?

```
#!/bin/sh
# 
Folders=(CONTROL GROUP1 GROUP2)
SC=(CPAKS_02 CPAKS_03 CPAKS_04 CPAKS_05 CPAKS_06 CPAKS_07) 
data_source=/Users/sheena/Desktop/test

cd ${data_source}

for j in ${Folders[@]}; do
  for i in ${SC[@]}; do
    cd ${data_source}/${j}/${i}
    cp ${data_source}/design.fsf ${data_source}/${j}/${i}/${i}_design.fsf
      for k in ${i}_design.fsf; do
        sed -i -e 's,'/Users/sheena/Desktop/DTI/CPAKS_03/fmri','${data_source}/${j}/${i}/${i}_fmri.nii',' ${i}_design.fsf
      done  
  done
done
```

Comment: `/bin/sh` is not bash (even if your `/bin/sh` is a symlink to bash, it runs in POSIX compatibility mode, with all bash extensions disabled), and `sed` is not part of bash. The bash tag has no place in this question. (If you **want** to use bash, your script should start with `#!/bin/bash` instead).

Comment: Also, you have a bunch of quoting issues here; run your code through http://shellcheck.net/

Comment: ...and consider using a more portable alternative to the nonstandard (and thus differing-between-operating-systems) `sed -i`; BashFAQ #21 -- at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021 -- discusses several.

Comment: On second thought, does the '-i' always need to be used in conjunction with the '-e'? If so, why is this?

Comment: No, there's nothing that requires `-i` and `-e` to be used together. Using `-e` is best-practice regardless of whether `-i` is in use, as it disambiguates that the search string is an argument rather than an option.

Comment: ...actually, rereading this code, the `#!/bin/sh` shebang is clearly in error -- the code requires a shell with arrays, such as ksh, bash, zsh, &c.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'm still trying to understand bash/sh/ksh, etc so perhaps the #!/bin/sh is an error. How can you tell from the code that it should be #!/bin/bash ?

Comment: `Folders=( CONTROL GROUP1 GROUP2 )` is syntax that isn't available in the POSIX sh standard; `#!/bin/sh` only promises a POSIX-sh shell, so functionality beyond that may or may not be available at runtime, depending on the platform and operating system.

Comment: (...and an OS upgrade can change this; for instance, Debian made an ash derivative their `/bin/sh` as of version 6.10, so any scripts using `#!/bin/sh` but requiring bashisms broke as of that release).

Comment: ...by the way, I just ran your code through http://shellcheck.net/ -- as mentioned in an earlier comment -- and note that it detects and reports this: "SC2039: In POSIX sh, arrays are undefined.", with a link to https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2039

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using BSD (OSX).

`-i` tells sed to change the file in place with the option of creating a backup file.  For BSD `sed`, unlike GNU (Linux) `sed`, the `-i` option *requires* an argument.  The argument specifies the suffix used for the backup file.  If you don't want a backup file, use `sed -i '' -e ...`.  The empty argument, `''`, tells BSD `sed` not to save a backup.

In other words, in your case, the `sed -i -e ...` command was interpreted as specifying a `-e` suffix for the backup file.  If you don't want a backup, use `sed -i '' -e ...`